# Statically Init a derived class

Tags: c++

With c++, Is there a way to get a derived class to inherit its own static initializer? I am trying to do something like the following:

```
class Base {

public:
        class StaticInit {
                public:
                virtual StaticInit() =0;
        };
};



class Derived: public Base {
  public:
        virtual StaticInit::StaticInit() {
           //do something with the derived class
        }
        static StaticInit init;
  }

static Derived::StaticInit init;
```

it would also be nice if I didn't have to define the init var in each derived class. I am currently redefining the StaticInit internal class in each derived class but it seems redundant.

Each derived class is a singleton, and I need the instance to be stored in a lookup table at program startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use templates to do this, rather than inheritance - something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct StaticInit {
     StaticInit() {
         // do whatever with T
     }
};
```

in use:

```
static StaticInit <SomeClass> init;
```

Comment: I basically went with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <class D>
class Base {
public:
    class StaticInit {
    public:
        StaticInit() { D::initStatic(*this); }
    };
    static StaticInit init;
};

template <class D>
Base<D>::StaticInit init;

class Derived: public Base<Derived> {
public:
    initStatic(Base<Derived>::StaticInit& s) {
        // Do derived-specific initialisation on s.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a compiler error at the line Base<D>::StaticInit init;
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘init’

I think that should be Base<D>::StaticInit Base<D>::init;
but I still get same error but now before Base<D>